# can't find gentelella-master fa-chevron-up icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question is about [Gentelella Alela template](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/)

In this HTML page, there is an icon with `class="fa fa-chevron-up"` that displays an icon to close the panel (See HTML code at line: 294). When the panel is closed, another icon image should appear to re-open the panel again but I can't find it in the HTML page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

its a `CSS` you will not found it in your `HTML`

but you can reach the style at this file:

`[url..]/assest/template/vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`

Answer (score 0):

The "magic" is somewhere in the custom(.min).js

```
$(".collapse-link").on("click",function(){
...
t.toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down")
```

there is a click handler that changes the class from fa-chevron-up to fa-chevron-down and back again every time you click.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help.

In fact, I did a big mistake! I changed the "fa fa-chevron-up" icon to a Bootstrap glyphicon (in HTML line 249)! In fact, if you change that icon name in HTML to a "Bootstrap glyphicon" the provided javascript will not display the "fa-chevron-down" icon!

Thank you.